# How to sum the rows containing some same marks without redundancy？

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file with multiple columns like:

```
                                       Ko_class  FPKM  count
0                       Carbon;Pyruvate;vitamins  16.7      1
1  Pyruvate;Carbohydrate;Pentose and glucuronate  30.0      7
2                         Lipid;Carbon;Galactose  40.5      9
3                  Galactose;Pyruvate;Fatty acid  57.0     10
4                               Fatty acid;Lipid  22.0      4
```

I want to sum the row values of `alls[FPKM]` and  `alls[count]` according to the `target_list`, and at the same time, all the values could be summed only once.

**Here is my data.**

```
# coding=utf-8
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

classes = [('Carbon;Pyruvate;vitamins', 16.7, 1),
         ('Pyruvate;Carbohydrate;Pentose and glucuronate', 30, 7),
         ('Lipid;Carbon;Galactose', 40.5, 9),
         ('Galactose;Pyruvate;Fatty acid', 57, 10),
         ('Fatty acid;Lipid', 22, 4)]
labels = ['Ko_class','FPKM', 'count']
alls = pd.DataFrame.from_records(classes, columns=labels)
print(alls)


target_list = ['Carbon','Carbon; Pyruvate','Galactose; Pyruvate; Carbon',
               'Galactose;Pyruvate;Fatty acid; Carbon']
```

**Here is what I want:**

```
                               Ko_class   FPKM  count
0                                 Carbon   57.2     10
1                       Carbon; Pyruvate  144.2     27
2            Galactose; Pyruvate; Carbon  144.2     27
3  Galactose;Pyruvate;Fatty acid; Carbon  166.2     31
```

As you can see, despite the rows `Carbon; Pyruvate` and `Galactose; Pyruvate; Carbon` is not same, could have the same `FPKM` and `count` value.

Hope someone could help me:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input

```
classes = [('Carbon;Pyruvate;vitamins', 16.7, 1),
         ('Pyruvate;Carbohydrate;Pentose and glucuronate', 30, 7),
         ('Lipid;Carbon;Galactose', 40.5, 9),
         ('Galactose;Pyruvate;Fatty acid', 57, 10),
         ('Fatty acid;Lipid', 22, 4)]
labels = ['Ko_class','FPKM', 'count']
alls = pd.DataFrame.from_records(classes, columns=labels)
target_list = ['Carbon','Carbon; Pyruvate','Galactose; Pyruvate; Carbon', 'Galactose;Pyruvate;Fatty acid; Carbon']
```

Create mask to filter all class in ko_class compare to all class in target list

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
for target in target_list:
    mask = alls.apply(lambda x: any([cls in target for cls in x['Ko_class'].split(';')]), axis=1) #here the mask compare class
    target_sum = alls.loc[mask, ["FPKM", 'count']].sum().reset_index().rename(columns={0:target}).iloc[:,1:] #sum of each class filtered by target in target list
    result = pd.concat([result,target_sum], axis=1) #concat as result
```

and then transpose it and rename the columns.

```
result = result.T
result.columns = ['FPKM', 'Count']
```

Output

```
                                        FPKM    Count
Carbon                                   57.2   10.0
Carbon; Pyruvate                        144.2   27.0
Galactose; Pyruvate; Carbon             144.2   27.0
Galactose;Pyruvate;Fatty acid; Carbon   166.2   31.0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. but it is apparently slower than other code in my mac, is this because of my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Use set operations in a loop with `concat`:

```
tmp = alls.assign(target=[set(re.split(r'\s*;\s*', s)) for s in alls['Ko_class']])

t = target_set[0]

out = pd.concat({label: tmp.loc[[x.issuperset(t) for x in tmp['target']], ['FPKM', 'count']].sum()
 for label, t in zip(target_list, target_set)
}).unstack().rename_axis('Ko_class').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
                                Ko_class  FPKM  count
0                                 Carbon  57.2   10.0
1                       Carbon; Pyruvate  16.7    1.0
2            Galactose; Pyruvate; Carbon   0.0    0.0
3  Galactose;Pyruvate;Fatty acid; Carbon   0.0    0.0
```